# How to handle a auto tab in angular4

Tags: angular

I need to move the next text box after typing in text from first text box. It has to auto move after typing text in first tab to next tab.

```
<div class="autotabbed-container">
  <div id="example1" class="autotabbed">
    <h3>Bank sort code: XX-XX-XX</h3>
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
    -
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
    -
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When I type the text in first text box the cursor need to move next text box. Please help how to achieve this in angular 4.

Same code is not working if I want apply in ngFor. In below code if I want to display text box based on ngFor loop. In first td I will display the password text boxes and next td I will display only star. In this case how we can dynamically apply #input. I need to point only first td items not next td items. So in this case how we can achieve auto focus.

```
<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let i of dynamicArr, let x = index">
    <td *ngIf="i !== '*'">
      <input type="password" #input1 formControlName="dyna{{i}}" id="dyna{{i}}" (input) = "onInputEntry($event, input2)" required maxlength="1" />
    </td>
    <td *ngIf=" i === '*' ">
      <img class="flotado_right" id="starimage" src="starimage.jpg" class="dot-image">        
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

I am building dynamic array like below and dynamic text is have values like 2 5 and 7. Inthis case dynamicArr[2] = 1,   dynamicArr[5] = 2 ,dynamicArr[7] = 3        so other values of values of dynamicArr is *

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (((i + 1) === this.dynamictext[0])) {
    this.dynamicArr[i] = '1';
  } else if (((i + 1) === this.dynamictext[1])) {
    this.dynamicArr[i] = '2';
  } else if (((i + 1) === this.dynamictext[2])) {
    this.dynamicArr[i] = '3';
  } else {
    this.dynamicArr[i] = '*';
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to angular so i don't know how to write a code to acheive this scenario.

Comment: how your identifying that the user has completed typing?

Comment: by using required maxlength="2"  i am make sure that he will enter only two characters to the text box

Comment: Is this in an already existing angular application, or are you starting fresh and only needing to do this one this?  if so, angular is way overkill for this.

Comment: This is fresh application with angular 4. It's company decision so i can't control the requirement. So Please help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done like this
HTML

```
<tr>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let i of dynamicArr, let x = index">
   <td *ngIf="i !== '*'">
     <input #tab type="password" id="tab{{i}}" required maxlength="1" class="tab" (input)="onInputEntry($event,'tab',(i))" />
   </td>
   <td *ngIf=" i === '*' " class="image">&</td>
 </ng-container>
</tr>
```

component

```
onInputEntry(event, id, nextInputIndex) {
  let input = event.target;
  let nexInput = +nextInputIndex + 1;
  let newID = id + nexInput;
  document.getElementById(newID).focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Sooraj.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, as this answer interacts directly with the DOM element and is not standard Angular 4/5 practice.

Comment: @blueprintChris If Possible could you please give solution for dynamic input auto focus so that it will useful for others.

Comment: Sure, please see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you want re-usable code try with a custom directive.

**Directive**:

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoTab]'
})
export class AutoTabDirective {
  @Input('appAutoTab') appAutoTab

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target']) onInput(input) {
    const length = input.value.length
    const maxLength = input.attributes.maxlength.value
    if (length >= maxLength) {
      this.appAutoTab.focus()
    }
  }
}
```

(remember to import the directive in the app.module)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AutoTabDirective
  ]})
```

**HTML**

```
<input #input1 type="text" maxlength="2" [appAutoTab]="input2"/>
<input #input2 type="text" maxlength="2"/>
```

Comment: This is good code and works well, and imo is cleaner than the accepted answer. However, try to include an explanation of your code for a more complete answer next time.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `(input)` event and template reference variables (`#var`) to determine if another element should be selected.

```
<input #input1 type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" (input)="onInputEntry($event, input2)" />
-
<input #input2 type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />

---

// component 
onInputEntry(event, nextInput) {
  let input = event.target;
  let length = input.value.length;
  let maxLength = input.attributes.maxlength.value;

  if (length >= maxLength) {
    nextInput.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Jens, Could you please help on me know how to handle in case of *ngFor. I have tried with edited  code in above..

Comment: If you’re using an ngFor and the content is not static, I don’t believe you can dynamically create template reference variables. You will probably need to inject the ElementRef service in the component, dynamically create IDs for the inputs, then target them that way. This seems like not a good idea though for an input form  as I’d think the form inputs would be fairly static.

Comment: I am not aware how to bind this dynamic templates. Could you please create plunker example or solution  for this special scenario. That will helps me alot.

Comment: What I’m saying is you can’t creat dynamic template reference variables. You’ll need another approach. You’re better off not using ngFor an making the form elements static.  If you’re set on using ngFor, feel free to set up a base plunkr and I can guide you from there.

Comment: i have added basic plunkar. Please help on this issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/jPbgOabiydHX0M9AOrCt?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry the plunkr doesn't render anything, there don't appear to be any angular libraries included. I'd recommend using this plunkr as a base template: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5.  I took a look through the code that's there and maybe you want to go with a different approach, use a queue to store the possible input indexes, and set a box to active if it's at the top of the queue and it's requirements have been met. Probably add logic to not set it to inactive on mouseclick.  Anyways a little hard to say without seeing a bit more details on how the data is sourced.

Comment: I have updated the base plunkar. As i knowThere is no queue concept in angular. So how we can store input in queue.

Comment: When you updated the plunkr did it generate a new URL? The existing one is not updated. I was simply suggesting you implement your own simple queue data structure to hold the information.  If you have a plunkr that shows a bit more of what you want to do with a semi-working example I can try to help you out more.

Comment: Yes its created new url, But i have givenwrong one. Below is the correct one. http://plnkr.co/edit/WR8nKcA407ShDfJhm5bf?p=preview . Please help  from here.

Answer (score 3):

Get the element through Renderer2 via ViewChild and focus, like so:

HTML:

```
<input #input1 type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" (keydown.enter)="focusInput2()"/>
<input #input2 type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" />
```

TypeScript:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _renderer2: Renderer2)

  @ViewChild('input2') private input2: ElementRef;

  focusInput2(){
      this._renderer2.selectRootElement(this.input2["nativeElement"]).focus();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

When you press enter on the first input, it will focus second input. This of course is down to the discrepancy of when you want the focus to happen.

Comment: Thanks @blueprintChris. is this works for dynamic inout also or only for static input only. Means if input is changes based on the key which come from for loop. if you see above ngFor example we are generating dynamic input element in that case above solution will work?.

Comment: @user3198259 yes, just wrap it in a `setTimeout()` function. If you try to reference a dynamic input then the chances are it could fail because the reference will point to undefined before the input has had chance to render

`setTimeout( ()=> {
   this.focusInput2();
}, 1000);`